# C# reflection usage, instantiating arbitrary class completely

Tags: c#, reflection

The short and broad version of my question is how do I instantiate and set each field in the below class **IF** I'm unaware of its members at compile time **BUT** it's reliable to assume the class structure's smallest fields are either a `ValueType` or a `System.String` field.

More specific: I've made a user control that acts like the watch window in VS. So it's an interface for exploring objects and setting them. I've gone through the assembly, found the class and looked at all the properties and pulled them out. That's all done and I'm left with things like

```
[datum][array] = 4; // intending to make 4 indexes
[datum][0][id] = 100;  
[datum][0][name] = "this data";  
[datum][0][value] = 200;
```

Now all i'm trying to do is figure out how to instantiate and set this data class. Below is an example class that I have to work with, they're created from XML so their structure is predictable.

```
public partial class myData {
    
    private myDataDatum datumField;
    public myDataDatum datum {
        get {
            return this.datumField;
        }
        set {
            this.datumField = value;
        }
    }
}
public partial class myDataDatum {
    private string nameField;
    private uint valueField;
    private ushort idField;
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
    public uint value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
    public ushort id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing right now, which isn't a complete solution because, well I'm stuck trying to use reflection. I'm not sure how to set values In arrays or other complex types.

```
Type type = ClassType;
object _class = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
{
    for(int i = 0; i<arraySizeof( p.Name ); i++ )
        _class.GetType().GetProperty( p.Name ).SetValue(_class, findValue(p.Name) )
}
```

The `findValue(string)` method just figured everything out and returns the right data. What I can't figure out is how to address thing's inside of another type? Do i have to make a new instance of that new type and assign it's values before I add it to the datum array?

---

### EDIT:

When I do this recursively, which isn't necessary, look at the structure of the source code. this is how I do it, and i get a lot of extra results, that, for me, are garbage data.

```
public void walkObject(Type t, string s)
{
  object _class = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
  foreach (var p in _class.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
  {

  Debug.WriteLine( "[" + t.Name + "]["+ s +"."+ p.Name + "]\t\t is of type " + p.PropertyType);

  if(p.PropertyType.IsClass && p.PropertyType.Assembly == t.Assembly  )
    walkObject( p.PropertyType, p.Name );
  }
}
```

Now all there is left to do is return the objects? Or how do I call handle a call to .SetValue?

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion?

Comment: What is arraySizeof(p.Name) doing? I don't see any arrays in the example data types you've showed. Are they being inserted into some other type? In general, if you want to go for full reflection to handle anything your algorithm will have to be recursive. This means that yes, you do need to create new instances for every datum in the array and fill their values before you insert it.

Comment: Right so, what's the property I need to look at when I need to recurs? Looking at what PropertInfo gives me, there doesn't seem to be a easy way to tell is the type has properties that are data members. EDIT: also that method just gets the amount of indexes if there are any set for that property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what someone needs to fill out a generic class of arbitrary complexity when the classes  base-most parameters are simple types (Value or string types).

More: This check `p.PropertyType.IsClass && p.PropertyType.Assembly == t.Assembly` is to ensure a "complex" type is recognized as any type specifically from the dynamically imported assembly.

```
    public object walkObjectConstructor(Type t, ref dynamic x)
    {

        foreach (var p in t.GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            /* upper level objects */
            if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && p.PropertyType.Assembly == t.Assembly)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine( p.Name );
                object _class = Activator.CreateInstance( p.PropertyType );
                walkObjectConstructor(p.PropertyType, ref _class);
                x.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).SetValue(x, _class, null);
            }
            /* inside the last upper level object */
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine( "\t" + p.Name);
                x.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).SetValue(x, defaultVal(p.PropertyType), null);
                return null;
            }

        }
        return x;
    }
```

Just calling `defaultVal(parameters to match)`, a method that will look-up a value based on whatever parameters are needed to be met will return a proper value.